# How do I call PARAM values nested in a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Ruby: 2.0**

**Rails: 4.0**

I am attempting to pull answer choices from my quiz application. Users select the radio button for =what they believe to be the correct answer in this form:

```
<%= form_tag do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :quiz_id, @quiz.id %>
    <% @quiz.questions.each do |question| %>
        <div class="question">
            <p><%= question.text %></p>
            <ul>
                <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
                    <% if answer.text.length > 0 %>
                        <li>
                            <%= radio_button_tag "[questions][#{question.id}]selected_answer", answer.id %>
                            <%= answer.text %>
                        </li>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= submit_tag "Score this Quiz" %>
<% end %>
```

These parameters seem to be coming through okay - you can see them in the log using Spike:

[image: Spike Screenshot]

However, I cannot figure out how to make a call to these parameters, here is my controller logic:

```
def score
   @answers = []
   @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:quiz_id])
   @quiz.questions.each do |question|
       @answers << params[:questions[question.id][:selected_answer]]
   end
end
```

But that throws the error: `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer`

How do I go about grabbing the `selected_answer` for each question?

**Update:**

I have made the changes recommended in the comments:

form

```
<%= radio_button_tag "questions[#{question.id}][selected_answer]", answer.id %>
```

controller

```
@quiz.questions.each do |question|
    @answers << params[:questions][question.id][:selected_answer]
end
```

This is now giving me this error: `undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass` On this line:

```
@answers << params[:questions][question.id][:selected_answer]
```

Comment: `no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer` comes whenever you will be trying to access array element by using string instead of fixnum indices...

Comment: @Babai I don't think I understand you advice well enough to make a correction. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just looks like a typo. Should be:

`@answers << params[:questions]["#{question.id}"][:selected_answer]`

Note the slightly different placement of brackets.

Also, we may need to translate the `question.id` to a string, since the params hash will have string keys (it's a `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, so you can also use symbols, but I think not integers).

Comment: Are you sure you've got a value for every question in @quiz.questions? This error most likely means that in your `each` block one of `params[:questions][question.id]` is nil for some value of `question.id`. But it's hard to say for sure without more information.

Comment: You might also try doing some string interpolation - I'm not sure if `HashWithIndifferentAccess` works with int keys or just strings/symbols. That is, maybe you need `params[:questions]["#{question.id}"]`.

Comment: Yes. But to double check myself - I checked the logs, saw that `3` was one of the parameters, and updated the line to: `@answers << params[:questions][3][:selected_answer]` and got the same error.

Comment: Nailed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are looking for

```
<%= radio_button_tag "questions[#{question.id}][selected_answer]", answer.id %>
```

And you your controller

```
@answers << params[:questions][question.id][:selected_answer]
```

You can see exactly the content of `params` in the log. Take a look at `questions` and you will be able to see the exact structure in ruby code.